# How do I output a 2D array to a Google Sheet?

Tags: multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of teams that have been ranked, and I want to put them up in groups of three.  Here is an example:

```
   Team Name       Rank
Example Team #1     1
Example Team #2     2
Example Team #3     3
Example Team #4     4
Example Team #5     5
Example Team #6     6
Example Team #7     7
Example Team #8     8
Example Team #9     9
Example Team #10    10
Example Team #11    11
Example Team #12    12
```

I want the end result to output something that looks like this to a Google Sheet:

```
Example Team #1    Example Team #8    Example Team #9
Example Team #2    Example Team #7    Example Team #10
Example Team #3    Example Team #6    Example Team #11
Example Team #4    Example Team #5    Example Team #12
```

Here is what I've come up with so far to accomplish that:

```js
function TournMatch(Teams, Rank) {
  var NumTeams = MyCountIf(Teams, "#blank") - 2;
  var OrdTeams = Array(NumTeams);

  for (var ind = 2; ind < NumTeams + 2; ind++) {
    OrdTeams[ind - 2] = Teams[Number(Rank[ind]) + 1];
  }

  var ActMatches = Math.floor(NumTeams/3);
  var InactTeams = NumTeams - ActMatches*3;

  if (InactTeams == 0) {
    var MatchUps = MyTranspose(Array(FillArray(ActMatches, 1, 1),
                                     FillArray(ActMatches, 2*ActMatches, -1),
                                     FillArray(ActMatches, 2*ActMatches + 1, 1)))
  } else if (InactTeams == 1) {
    var MatchUps = MyTranspose(Array([1].concat(FillArray(ActMatches, 2, 1)),
                                    [""].concat(FillArray(ActMatches, 2*ActMatches + 1, -1)),
                                    [""].concat(FillArray(ActMatches, 2*ActMatches + 2, 1))))
  } else if (InactTeams == 2) {
    var MatchUps = MyTranspose(Array([1].concat(FillArray(ActMatches, 2, 1)),
                                     FillArray(ActMatches + 1, 2*ActMatches + 2, -1),
                                     [""].concat(FillArray(ActMatches, 2*ActMatches + 3, 1))))
  }

  // This set of for-loops is where the problem occurs.
  for (var ind1 = 0; ind1 < MatchUps.length; ind1++) {
    for (var ind2 = 0; ind2 < MatchUps[ind1].length; ind2++) {
      if (MatchUps[ind1][ind2] != "") {
        MatchUps[ind1][ind2] = OrdTeams[MatchUps[ind1][ind2] - 1];
      }
    }
  }

  return MatchUps
}
```

Everything works exactly as I would expect until the last (double) for-loop.  In fact, if I comment that portion of the code out, I get the rank of the team that should get put in that position, like this:

```
1    8    9
2    7    10
3    6    11
4    5    12
```

Furthermore, if I output `OrdTeams`, instead of `MatchUps`, I get a list of the teams properly ordered according to the specified rank.  In the last set of for-loops, I'm just trying to replace the specified team rank with the corresponding team name from `OrdTeams`.  Instead, what I end up getting is absolutely nothing.  That is, the array that is output to the spreadsheet is completely empty.

This seems like something that should be simple, so my mistake is probably staring me in the face.  Can anyone here see the mistake I'm making?

P.S.  [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZhACcpBXPkqnMk1dy6HcW_ouseAj-W3Ofu5yLwbCuYU/edit?usp=sharing) is an example Google Sheet that should be editable to anyone with the link.  I have included the code above along with all my "helper" functions in the script file.  Please let me know if there is any further information you need.

Comment: Can you clarify if the number of teams would be a constant value or it may change? Also from where the parameters teams and ranks are being passed and also where are you calling the TournMatch(Teams, Rank) function from?

Comment: The number of teams may change (i've tested this, and have it working satisfactorily).  The function is getting called as a custom function from the sheet (i.e. where I want the data output to).  Check out the example sheet I linked to in the postscript.

Comment: I've added some clarification to hopefully make it more clear what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Can you post the MatchUps array output before the (double)for loop? Would be helpful to get an idea what it is giving.

Comment: @tlewis3348, how does rank factor into the situation. It looks like it's ignored as an output in your example, and it looks like it doesn't factor into the sorting of the output.

Comment: @raiderrobert This is a very simplistic case where the input teams are already in order.  However, I want the ability to specify a rank that does not coincide with the order of the teams.  I have tested this, and it works fine.  Ultimately though, whether or not the teams are in the correct order or not doesn't matter.  I just want them to at least be output in some order, no matter what it is, at this point.

Comment: I should also mention that I can get it to output a single column of teams by doing `return MatchUps[n]`, where `n` is the index of any column in the `MatchUps` array, but I can't get it to output all the columns at once.

Answer (score 1):

Down Up Down by Rank

```
function TournMatch(teams, ranks) {
  for(var i = 0; i < teams.length; i++ ) {
    teams[i].unshift((ranks[i][0] + 1000000).toString());
  }
  teams.sort();
  var rows = Math.ceil(teams.length / 3);
  var x = 0;
  var out = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < rows ; i++ ) {
    out[i] = [];
    out[i][0] = teams[i][1];
    out[i][1] = teams[i - 1 + 2 * rows - 2 * x][1];
    x++;
    if(i + 2 * rows < teams.length ) {
    out[i][2] = teams[i + 2 * rows][1];
    }
  }
  return out;
}
```

Comment: It's late and this is crazy. Maybe I will annotate tomorrow. Entertaining.

Comment: Well, that looks a lot more concise than mine, and is probably a lot more efficient, but ultimately, the `out` array is still showing up as blank in my Google Sheet.  I have updated the example sheet links in the postscript of the question with your function.  You should have full editing ability, so you can see both the sheet and the apps script for the sheet.  Thanks!

Comment: Using the actual data as parameters for your function:  =TournMatch(Sheet1!I3:I14,Sheet1!J3:J14) instead if entire columns will cause the function to work properly.

Comment: If you want to use arrays that include a bunch of extraneous non-data then the first thing you need to do is clean up the arrays so they contain only data and are the same size. I understand what you want to do and have myself spent hours perfecting a script that will give me the flexibility to save 5 minutes a year but that is on you.

Comment: Hmmm... Okay, I guess I'll just have to figure out a way to determine where the data is that I want using in-cell formulas rather than apps script functions.  Thanks for the help!